# How to traverse to correct model when I have composite primary key

Tags: laravel

I am struggling to figure out how to display the proper data to the view when I have a composite primary key.

I have two tables involved:

1. user_to_drug_mappings:  contains columns for user_id, pharma_ApplNo, pharma_ProductNo
2. pharma_products:  contains columns for ProductNo, ApplNo, Form.  The combination of the ProductNo and ApplNo in this table form a composite primary key.  I am not sure if that has to be defined somewhere in my migrations.

I have the following in my controller:

```php
//Query UserToDrugMappings table for all of user's records
$drugs = DB::table('user_to_drug_mappings')
    ->where('user_id', $user)
    ->get();

    return view ('my-health-hub', compact('drugs'));
```

I have the following in my view:

```html
    @foreach($drugs as $drug)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$drug->pharma_ApplNo }}</td>
            <td>{{$drug->pharma_ProductNo }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Now I need to somehow use the ApplNo and ProductNo to search the pharma_products table and display the Form column within my view.  I don't know how I would do this

Comment: do you mean search by AppINo **OR** ProductNo?

Comment: That's the issue.  I need to search the pharma_products table using ApplNo AND ProductNo.  I think that is called a composite primary key